# Azure DevOps : BlackDuck Setup

Tags: azure-devops, scanning

we are trying to setup blackduck on our on prem agent. But whenever we run the blackduck scan we are facing the System.Net.WebException warning.
The agent is trying to download the blackduck over https and it's failing. Please provide a solution.

Comment: It's on prem agent, you can manually setup black duck on the machine, no need to install via the pipeline. But if you'd like to, please check local network setting, make sure it's not blocked. Meanwhile, you can elaborate a bit more on what you're actually trying to do, and the error details for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The problem was on our side. we were using the old version of Blackduck. After using the new version (Synopsys Scan) we are getting the results.

Comment: Glad to know it's resolved!