# Configuring Black Duck in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, devops, blackduck

We already have a black duck server configured and we have a server URL. How can we use this server as an end point in Azure Devops pipeline without installing any build agent since we need to select end point from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Black Duck for TFS and Azure DevOps is architected to integrate seamlessly with TFS and Azure DevOps build and release pipelines.

[image]

For further information, you can go through this [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827898/azure-devops-blackduck-setup) and [Black Duck](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=black-duck-software.detect-for-tfs)